# Getting "group by" information from the ResultSet metadata

Tags: java, group-by, metadata

I have a query in Java from which I get some information. The thing is, I need to know the names of the columns used for the group by, and the query is formed in such a way that I can't simply pull them out from them, so I want to know if there's a way to get that information from the meta data, or in any other way after the query is consumed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't.

`ResultSetMetaData` only describes the returned `ResultSet` and not your query.

Comment: It seems to be that way. Been looking for a method with the ResultSet and with the PreparedStatement types, but couldn't found nothing. I will have to find another way.